# Parse SEC Edgar on Pyhthon

Tags: javascript, python, scraping, table

I would like to scrape tables from the SEC such as [this one](https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/viewer?action=view&cik=1341439&accession_number=0001193125-18-201034&xbrl_type=v).

However, there is some JavaScript involved, and I don't know how to access specific tables, such as `CONSOLIDATED BALANCE SHEETS`.

Is there any existing package on Python that already do this job?

If not, can you recommend any resource to learn how to complete this task? (I'm currently trying with BeautifulSoup and PyQt4, but I can't make it work)